# navigation bar button do not show

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

Why I have a button on my navigation bar in storyboard, but it doesn't show when simulating?
I attach a screenshot below, please someone take a look

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUO7D.png)

[when simulating, button doesn't show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDArp.png)

Comment: Have you given autolayout constraints to it?

Comment: No, I haven't, and I tried auto layout, I didn't work either.

Comment: Try to add bar button item.

Comment: Here is the thing. I have a a tab bar controller, which is the root view of a navigation controller, and I want to add a button on the navigation bar of one of the view controllers of the tab bar controller. But it won't let me directly add button on the navigation bar, I should first add a navigation item, and them bar button item. What I could not get is why it shows on the story board but not in the simulator, and from the screenshot you can tell there is a navigation bar, but nothing on it. It's weird.

Comment: try moving the button full left or full right depending on where you want it to be and some blue lines will show up. put it in those blue lines and then go down to the storyboard and click reset to suggested constraints(4 icons choose the 4th)